# Backup Pebble App

Tags: backup, pebble

I have owned and loved a pebble time smartwatch for about a year now. Because of Pebble's recent demise, I'm considering buying an extra pebble time in order to replace my current one when it eventually kicks the bucket. However, there is no guarantee that the Android app and pebble app store will still be available when my current watch kicks the bucket, or even when I need to replace or factory reset my phone.

Is there a way to make an offline backup of the watch's current state and the app, such that it would be possible to install the Pebble app on a new Android phone from the current copy, which includes all the apps I've installed for the watch?

My goal is to preserve the app and watch configuration indefinitely for as long as possible, which I think I can do if I can successfully preserve my current copy of the app. Is that possible? Will there be any problems if I update to a newer version of Android? (My current phone is running Android Marshmallow 6.0.1). And overall, will this achieve my goal of using a pebble watch for several more years?

Comment: To stay more future-proof, may I rather recommend you switching over to [Gadgetbridge](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge)? Doesn't cover the full spectrum of the "official app" and probably won't, because it doesn't use the Pebble cloud; but the latter will be gone for good soon anyway. // I've never used the official app, but started with GB straight away almost a year ago (Time Steel here). Works stable, active development, active support. Covers other devices as well. // As for your question: Try `adb backup -f pebble.ab -apk com.getpebble.android.basalt` :)